# I got a list of tuples and i want to get the second element of each tuples in the list

Tags: haskell

Something like `[(1,"blue"),(4,"red"),(2,"yellow")]` will become `["blue","yellow","red"]`.

---

```
ballots :: [Ballot]
ballots = [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6]

b1 = ["Blue","Green"]

b2 = ["Green","Blue","Red"]

b3 = ["Blue"]

b4 = ["Red","Green"]

b5 = ["Blue","Red","Green"]

b6 = ["Green","Red"]`
```

ballots will put into the ns
I'm getting the first element of each b1 till b6 with head function which will be blue, green, blue, red, blue, green.

```
rank ns = results[head (x) | x<-ns]
```

results is a function I created, it will calculate the total of each color and gives the out like this  `[(1,"red"),(2,"green"),(3,"blue")]`

So, what i want to do now is an output without the int in `[(Int, String)]`
which looks like `["red","green","blue"]`

Comment: Are you sure you want `[("blue","yellow","red")]` and not `["blue","yellow","red"]`?

Comment: oops. this one ["blue","yellow","red"].

Comment: You're looking for `map snd`, but notice that your `ballots` is no list of tuples but of lists of strings rather?

Comment: when i use the function results which i created. it gives [(1,"blue"),(4,"red"),(2,"yellow")]. which i believe is tuples within tuples

Comment: @Bergi Thank you. You're the first person who help me. really appreciate it.

Comment: alternatively you can use list comprehensions for this as well.  i.e. `[ c | (i,c) <- [(1,"blue"),(4,"red"),(2,"yellow")] ]`

Answer (score 6):

`map`:

```
λ> :type map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
λ> :type snd
snd :: (a, b) -> b
λ> :type map snd
map snd :: [(a, b)] -> [b]
```

so:

```
λ> map snd [(1,"blue"),(4,"red"),(2,"yellow")]
["blue", "red", "yellow"]
```

If you want it sorted by the first element:

```
λ> import Data.List
λ> import Data.Function
λ> :t sortBy
sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
λ> :t sortBy (compare `on` fst)
sortBy (compare `on` fst) :: Ord a => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
```

So:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function

solution :: [(Int, String)] -> [String]
solution = map snd . sortBy (compare `on` fst)
```